# Can something real be an association to something else?

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, reality

Can some real thing, that exist, be an association to another thing?

What does of the image or real thing causes an associative effect?

Exist ergo real?

i also see the problem with *"there **is**"* construction, because *there is existing*, is not same that *one exists*. ***To be*** is the construction(?) of associating something with another thing by the signs - already is an associative thinking.

*There(this) is existing* - then **that exists**/**that has existed** and *this was endowed* existing sign of **that** by means of the association. But **that** wasn't associated of means.

The distinct between exist and to be:

There are unicorns - true.
Unicorns exist - false.

in this cause that *the one is* is not a sufficient condition **that one exist**.

Comment: The substantival reality of relations is a fairly open question, see ["Relations"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/relations/) in the SEP. If association is taken as intentional, see ["Are there intentional objects?"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intentionality/#TherInteObje) (also in the SEP).

Comment: @KristianBerry thank you, but i asked not about relations, but about reality, something  that existing in real, not intentional object. Or they are same things?

Comment: Hmm, what are you using the word "real" to describe? I interpreted "association to" as a relation between some X and what X is associated with, which is association-as-a-relation. Now some people deny that relations are real, though, or they say that relations have a lesser reality than monadic properties, etc.

Comment: @KristianBerry "X" that you tap ? real, or what exist? i think that real - something that exist, real because exist. That have not exist - not real. Unicorns have not exist - thay not real, but unicorns looking toys are exist, toys things are looks real, but toys meaning, game meaning of toys are not looks real, but belonging to relation, probably

Comment: @KristianBerry exist ergo real

Comment: Can anything exist, *except* relationally? Me & Buddhism say, nah: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prat%C4%ABtyasamutp%C4%81da

Comment: @CriglCragl has buddhism a word *real* in real or it is an association with some hindu/sanscit/pali(dialect) noun? *Sanskrit rayim, rayah* - is a prototype of the word real by etymology dictionary. Is this word is directly that about buddhism reads or not?

Comment: What do you mean by real items and by association? The local bridge is constructed from steel beams and concrete in a structure that persists from yesterday, to today, and into the future assuming conditions in the materials are sufficient to withstand the forces generated in the surroundings. Weight is a force due to gravity at the surface of earth due to near-earth surroundings. The components of the bridge are "coupled" by joints and structural features that seem to be real features of the structure but not any particular component. Are the components structurally coupled? Yes. Associated?

Comment: @SystemTheory they associated or coupled? what arts destruction of the methods?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reality_in_Buddhism

Comment: Something real is not necessarily a thing. Entities can exist in ways different than things exist, the word "exist" is [polysemic](https://iep.utm.edu/existenc/#H3). Redness is an "association to a thing", it exists in reality. Distance is an "association" of one thing to another, it also exists in reality. The distinction between existence and subsistence that you make at the end has been introduced by Meinong, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/possible-objects/#SubVsExi).

Answer (score 2):

The real problem here, I think, is that posing such a problem really ends up being sufficiently resolved with recourse to "the conditions of possibility in general". Ie, there has to be situation of sufficient cause for some existent framework that determines the possibility of you posing the question to us and such a question being intelligible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Every cause itself becomes an effect and an effect is the cause in a changed form.

[Cause and effect](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41669/cause-and-effect/41676#41676)

Since there is the other things are unreal, (which means there is no such thing) the answer to your main question is, ‘No’.  If you find there is, the other things are nothing but the real thing; as in the case of golden ornaments and gold.  Golden ornaments (the effect) are nothing but gold.

Comment: But if without *"there **is**"*? If no any need, no cause to find/or to search *what is* of existence?